# Cross browser DataTable sizing incorrectly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Recently I've been unable to get my DataTables to occupy 100% width of their div. I am using Bootstrap and jQuery. Any of you guys have any idea?

HTML

```
 <div class="form-group" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;">
    <div class="row">
     <br>
      <table data-role="table" id="datatables2" class="datatables display ui-responsive form-table" style="width: 100%;"> <!--Beginning Table -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Staff</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
      <th>Search</th>
      <th>Priority</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
  </tbody>
 </table> <!-- End Table -->
 </div>
```

CSS

```
table {
overflow-x: auto;
display: block;
width: 100% !important;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

jQuery

```
    aTable = $('table#datatables2').DataTable({
     scrollX: false,
     retrive: true,
     ordering: false,
     bFilter: false,
     bPaginate: false,
     bInfo: false,
     responsive: true
  });
```

Links / Scripts:

```
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/r-2.1.1/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.0/datatables.min.css"/>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.13/r-2.1.1/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Safari Image

[image]

Google Chrome Image

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting them centered and spaced evenly on the top row?

Comment: Correct! I basically want it to look like the safari image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the CSS for table, remove:

```
display: block;
```

This should make it look like the Safari image... otherwise:

If you want to center further than that, on the CSS for th with the class sorting_disabled add:

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: Ugh that was so simple, can't believe I didn't see it! Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're Welcome!  Some of the simplest errors are the hardest to find sometimes.